# Self LEFT JOIN on a subset of table

Tags: sql

There is a table of employees and some other columns such as salary, etc.

```
ID    | EmployeeId | Time
---------------------------
1     | 1          | '2019-09-05 00:08:34'
2     | 1          | '2019-03-03 00:12:16'
3     | 2          | '2019-04-12 01:08:04'
4     | 2          | '2019-08-20 04:08:12'
5     | 3          | '2019-05-05 05:08:42'
```

I want the latest ID for each employee, before a specific time.
So the return result for time before '2019-09-05 00:00:00' should be: 2, 4, 5

I run the following query but it doesn't return the expected result:

```
SELECT t1.ID FROM t AS t1 
     LEFT JOIN t AS t2 
         ON (t2.Time < '2019-09-05 00:00:00' AND t1.EMPLOYEE_ID = t2.EMPLOYEE_ID AND t1.Time < t2.Time)
     WHERE t2.Time IS NULL;
```

How can I self join on a subset of a table?

Comment: that's right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.employee_id = t.employee_id and
                      t2.time < '2019-09-05'
               );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when t.time < '2019-09-05' then t.time end) over (partition by t.employee_id) as max_time
      from t
     ) t
where time = max_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `row_num()` you can also use `max() group by`

```
select t1.ID from t t1
inner join (
 select row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by Time desc) as rn, ID from t) as t2 on t2.ID and t1.ID
where t2.rn = 1 and t1.Time < '2019-09-05 00:00:00'
```